# What do I get with an Xbox live subscription?

Tags: xbox-360

I recently bought a new Xbox 360 (with all it's built in Wi-Fi and 250GB sugary goodness) after my 4 year old Ex-Xbox 360 broke down last week. Now, since I have wifi built in, I am thinking of getting a live subscription for 1 year.

My question is this: If I get an Xbox Live subscription, will I be able to play all my games online against other members and friends, or do I pay for each game, on top of the subscription fee?

Comment: Welcome to Stack gaming.SE LocustHorde! I edited your question to remove your subquestion "Is it worth getting a subscription?" This is too subjective, and doesn't work well with our sites Q&A format. Your third question also falls under shopping recommendation, which is off-topic as outlined in our [faq.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) I also removed some of the text you put in with regards to which games you own to make it easier to read, since it didn't seem relevant to your question. Feel free to put that back in though.

Comment: @Wipqozn, is there something left in the question that isn't answered by [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/437/8366)? It might seem harsh to close as a duplicate, but perhaps that's the only objective question the OP asked.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis Harsh or not, I agree. The OP got an answer anyways, so I doubt he cares whether we close it nor not.

Comment: @Wipqozn, I wanted to get a general opinion on the subscription. Obviously, if majority of people say it's not good, then I wouldn't want to go with it/

Comment: @LocustHorde Asking for a general opinion is subjective and considered off-topic. Whether it's worth the money is up to you: Will *you* get enough enjoyment out of the online to justify it's cost?

Comment: @Wipqozn, ``will you get enough enjoyment`` .. that's exactly what I wanted to find out! anyway, thanks for editing the post to community standards :)

Comment: @LocustHorde  I know that's what you wanted to find out, which is what is considered off-topic. I will suggest that since your hesitant you may want to look at buying a 1-month subscription instead.

Comment: Also, when you have 20 rep you are able to talk in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35), depending on the time of day you may be able to find a few users willing to chime in with their opinion.

Comment: You get to be called a fag by idiot 13-year-olds in multiplayer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a gold membership, you will have the ability to play with friends & family online. Additional perks of having a gold membership can be found here:

[Xbox LIVE Membership](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/joinlive) (US only; compare with [UK](http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/Live/Join-Today) or [Australia](http://www.xbox.com/en-AU/live/joinlive))

You do not have to pay for online access per game you wish to play multiplayer in on top of the subscription fee, though some of the newer games have started implementing an "online pass" feature, which locks multiplayer access until you buy a pass from the Xbox Live Marketplace. These passes come free with new copies of those games, but for those who purchase used copies, you will have to purchase this separately.

I'm also assuming that you have an internet connection at your home? Otherwise the built-in wifi adapter wouldn't do you much good.

Comment: Hi @Kotsu, thank you very much, I had this question about the game passes as I had seen a code in UBisoft Assassins creed. That answered my question, thanks!